# Any tutorial for tapestry-mongodb module?

Tags: tapestry

I'm using Tapestry 5.4beta6 now and I can see there is tapestry-mongodb module. Is there any example how can I use this in an application? I found the former module on github but there is only a note that module is part of core framework but no docs or example ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tapestry-mongodb** is just wrapping the initialization of the MongoDB Java driver.
You're free to use whatever POJO-wrapper you like; there are plenty of them:

- Morphia - Type-Safe Wrapper with DAO/Datastore abstractions
- Mungbean (w/clojure support)
- Spring MongoDB – Provides Spring users with a familiar data access features including rich POJO mapping.
- DataNucleus JPA/JDO
  JPA/JDO wrapper
- lib-mongomapper
- JavaBean Mapper (No annotations)
- MongoJack – Uses jackson (annotations) to map to/from POJOs and has a simple wrapper around DBCollection to simply this.
- Kundera
- JPA compliant ORM. Works with multiple datastores.
- Jongo – Query in Java as in mongo shell (using strings), unmarshall results into Java objects (using Jackson)
- MongoLink – Object Document Mapper (ODM.) Uses a plain java DSL for mapping declaration.
  (Source: [docs.mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/#pojo-mappers))

I took this example from the tapestry-mongodb tests, which uses [Jongo](http://jongo.org) as ORM:

**Module**

```
public class MongoDBTestModule
{

    public static void contributeApplicationDefaults(MappedConfiguration<String, String> configuration)
    {
        configuration.add(MongoDBSymbols.DEFAULT_DB_NAME, "TapestryMongoTest");
    }


    public static void contributeMongoDBSource(OrderedConfiguration<ServerAddress> configuration)
    {
        try
        {
            configuration.add("test", new ServerAddress("localhost", 12345));
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Person entity:**

```
package org.apache.tapestry5.internal.mongodb;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 */
public class People
{
    private ObjectId _id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Date birthDate;


    public ObjectId get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(ObjectId _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
}
```

**Actual test code**

```
@Inject
MongoDB mongoDB;

void test() { 
    // ...
    org.jongo.Jongo jongo = new Jongo(mongoDB.getDefaultMongoDb());
    org.jongo.MongoCollection peoples = jongo.getCollection("peoples");
    // ...
}
```